# What is the first digit of $-10$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Generally, what is the first digit of a negative whole number? In case of $-10$, it can not be $-1$, because a digit is defined to be from $0$ to $9$. Is it $1$?  Or does it not have the first digit at all and it is just the first $number$ $-1$?

Comment: The minus is just a sign. It does not go with a digit.

Comment: I would say $1$ is the first digit. There are however 10-adic integers where $-10$ can be expressed by $..9990$ which actually doesn't have a leading digit, it has infinitely many of them, and all are $9$.

Comment: I believe you mis-typed the $0$ at the end of the $..999$. If it was deliberate, could you please give a little further explanation?

Comment: @SeanRoberson So you're saying the first digit is still $1$, correct?

Comment: Yes, the "first digit" of 19 or -19 is 1.

Comment: $1$ is the first digit because .... it is the first digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the first digit of $-10$ is $1$.